# Pyspark - hive dataframe sort by two columns breaks the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, pyspark, hive

I have an issue with sorting a dataframe from hdfs hive context.
trying to sort a dataframe of a similar structure to this:

```
+---+--------------+---------------+
| id|parameter_name|parameter_value
+---+--------------+---------------+
|id1|    name_en   |    value a
|id1|    name_il   |    value b
|id1|    address_en|    value c
|id1|    address_il|    value d
|id2|    name_il   |    value f
|id2|    name_en   |    value e
|id2|    address_il|    value h
|id1|    address_en|    value g
+---+--------------+---------------+
```

I am trying to sort this dataframe in a way that the id is sorted and the parameter_name sequence in the df for each id is as follows:

```
name_en
name_il
address_en
address_il
```

note that in the example that is not the case and the names and addresses between id's are flipped.

Trying to use df.sort(["id","parameter_name"]) yields mixed results, mixing the dataframe further and splitting the id to:

```
id1, name_en
id1, name_il
id2, name_il
id2, name_en
id1, address_en
id1, address_il
id2, address_il
id2, address_en
```

Comment: I do not get the same result when doing `df.sort(["id","parameter_name"])`.

Comment: This is a simplified example. The actual dataframe is in a hive and much bigger. In essence when sorting by multiple columns it orders the df by the first element, and then fixes any unsorted elements within each sorted group to be sorted as well. this breaks in my case and I am trying to understand if there's a workaround

Comment: what do you mean "break" ? it fails with an error ? what error ?

Comment: No there's no error. The returned table isn't sorted.
Instead of
id1, name_en
id1, name_il
id1, address_en
id1, address_il
id2, name_en
id2, name_il
id2, address_en
id2, address_il
which is sorted in the required way

it returns:
id1, name_en
id1, name_il
id2, name_il
id2, name_en
id1, address_en
id1, address_il
id2, address_il
id2, address_en

Comment: you do `df.sort(...); df.show()` ? or `df.sort(...).show()` ? or `df = df.sort(...); df.show()` ?`sort` is a transformation, it returns a dataframe. You need to assign back this dataframe to `df` if you want to save your transformation before executing the action `show` or `write`.

Comment: here's what i did:
    dataframe = dataframe.withColumn("ordering_col",
                                     when(dataframe.__getattr__(PARAMETER_NAME) == "name_en", 1)
                                     .when(dataframe.__getattr__(PARAMETER_NAME) == "name_il", 2)
                                     .when(dataframe.__getattr__(PARAMETER_NAME) == "address_en", 3)
                                     .otherwise(4))

then:

dataframe = dataframe.orderBy(["id", "ordering_col"])

then dataframe.show()

Comment: replace `dataframe.__getattr__(PARAMETER_NAME)` with `F.col(PARAMETER_NAME)`. Technically, you should no use double underscores `__METHOD_NAME__` methods directly in python scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I created your dataframe but assigned random values to `parameter_value` so the order is not relevant anymore.

```py
from random import random

data = [
    {"id": "id1", "parameter_name": "name_en", "parameter_value": random()},
    {"id": "id1", "parameter_name": "name_il", "parameter_value": random()},
    {"id": "id1", "parameter_name": "address_en", "parameter_value": random()},
    {"id": "id1", "parameter_name": "address_il", "parameter_value": random()},
    {"id": "id2", "parameter_name": "name_il", "parameter_value": random()},
    {"id": "id2", "parameter_name": "name_en", "parameter_value": random()},
    {"id": "id2", "parameter_name": "address_il", "parameter_value": random()},
    {"id": "id2", "parameter_name": "address_en", "parameter_value": random()},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df.show()
+---+--------------+-------------------+                                        
| id|parameter_name|    parameter_value|
+---+--------------+-------------------+
|id1|    address_il|0.11850447351294957|
|id2|       name_en|0.18902815459657452|
|id2|    address_il|  0.294998203578158|
|id1|    address_en|0.48741740190944827|
|id2|       name_il| 0.5651073044407224|
|id2|    address_en| 0.6530661784882391|
|id1|       name_il| 0.6797674631659714|
|id1|       name_en| 0.9887386653580036|
+---+--------------+-------------------+
```

then, I need to create an ordering column to maintain the artificial order you need :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

ordering_col = (
    F.when(F.col("parameter_name") == "name_en", 1)
    .when(F.col("parameter_name") == "name_il", 2)
    .when(F.col("parameter_name") == "address_en", 3)
    .when(F.col("parameter_name") == "address_il", 4)
)

df.orderBy("id", ordering_col).show()
+---+--------------+-------------------+
| id|parameter_name|    parameter_value|
+---+--------------+-------------------+
|id1|       name_en| 0.9887386653580036|
|id1|       name_il| 0.6797674631659714|
|id1|    address_en|0.48741740190944827|
|id1|    address_il|0.11850447351294957|
|id2|       name_en|0.18902815459657452|
|id2|       name_il| 0.5651073044407224|
|id2|    address_en| 0.6530661784882391|
|id2|    address_il|  0.294998203578158|
+---+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Nice! I completely screwed this one :'D

Comment: I will attempt this now. To my knowledge there is no need for something to keep the artificial order since parameter_name is a string and can be ordered just as such. In your case I would need to create an artificial order for id as well since it isn't an integer. Will let you know soon

Comment: @xMustangLovesPie well, alphabetical order is `address_en, address_il, name_en, name_il` (or the opposite - read it backward - if you order `desc`). So, you need that artificial ordering.

Comment: I should've pointed out that the point of my order was so that it repeats every time and doesn't get mishmashed somewhere in between. Anyway, I attempted your solution, and it works locally on a custom dataframe. But yet again, on the hive it simply doesn't reconstruct the dataframe properly. It splits it in the middle like so:

Comment: |id1| name_en| 0.9887|  
   
|id1|   name_il| 0.6797|  
   
|id2|name_en   |0.48741|  
   
|id2|name_il   |0.11850|  
   
|id3|   name_en|0.18902|  
   
|id3|   name_il| 0.5651|  
   
|id1|address_en|0.18902|  
|id1|address_il| 0.5650|  
|id2|address_en| 0.6530|  
|id2|address_il|  0.294|  
|id3|address_en|0.18902|  
|id3|address_il| 0.5651|  
+---+--------------+-------+`

as you may see, the id's are split..

Comment: @xMustangLovesPie i have nothing to say. You current case is not reproducible

Comment: Solved it by transforming the df topandas and then to csv. What a hassle. Hive context always makes things more convoluted. Locally everything works flawlessly and I can't even reproduce the issue myself :P thanks anyways and hopes this helps someone along the way. Posting solution now

Answer (score 0):

Simply transform the Pyspark dataframe to a Pandas dataframe and perform the sort operation. You may transform the dataframe back with `sparkContext.createDataFrame(panda_df)` like so:

```
panda_df = dataframe.toPandas().sort_values(["id", "parameter_name"], ascending=(True, False))
sorted_df = sparkContext.createDataFrame(panda_df)
sorted_df.show()
```

Comment: If your data fit the memory, then just use Pandas. You should use spark when data are too big to fit memory.